# How to compare and display kendo dirty flag upon editing only if the old value and new value are different before saving the grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In a kendo grid, in grid cell when I change a value kendo's dirty flag is displayed. But then when I click back to the same grid cell and change it to the previous value (already existing value) the dirty flag still appears.

How can I check whether the value is similar to the previous value and not display the dirty flag before saving.

Below is my code for kendo editable dropdown.

```
function editCategoryDropDown(container, options) {
    var catObject = JSON.parse(ticketProjectCategoryObject.value);
    $('<div  id="categoryDDTreeView" class="dropDownTreeViewStyle"/>').appendTo(container);
    var catDropDownTreeView = $("#categoryDDTreeView").kendoExtDropDownTreeView({
        treeview: {
            dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                data: catObject
            }),
            //expended: true,
            loadOnDemand: false,
            change: function (e) {
                {
                    var dropDownTreeViewObj = $('#categoryDDTreeView').find('.k-input');
                    var nodeTitle = dropDownTreeViewObj.attr("title");
                    if (nodeTitle != null) {
                        options.model.Category = nodeTitle;
                        options.model.CategoryId = dropDownTreeViewObj.attr("nodevalue")
                        options.model.dirty = true;
                        container.addClass("k-dirty-cell");
                    }
                };
            }
        },
    }).data("kendoExtDropDownTreeView");
    var dropDownBox = catDropDownTreeView.dropDownList();
    dropDownBox.text(options.model.Category)
    var treeView = catDropDownTreeView.treeview();
    var node = treeView.findByText(options.model.Category.split("|").pop().trim());
    treeView.select(node);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting task, so I invested some time in experimenting. Consider the following approach:

- in the [`edit`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit) event of the Grid, save the original state of the data item (`e.model.toJSON()`) in some variable. [`toJSON`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#methods-toJSON) is needed to strip the Kendo-specific fields and methods, convert the data item to a plain JavaScript object and break the automatic value updates that will otherwise occur, as the data item is passed by reference.

  ```
  edit: function(e) {
      var model = e.model;
      if (!originalDataItems[model.id]) {
          originalDataItems[model.id] = model.toJSON();
      }
  }
  ```
- in the [`save`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-save) event of the Grid, compare the new *dirty* values with the original data item values. If they are the same, apply a custom CSS class to the table cell. You will need to wrap the code in the `save` handler in `setTimeout`, because this event is fired before the edited cell has been closed and switched back to non-edit mode.

  ```
  save: function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      e.sender.tbody.find(".k-dirty-cell").each(function() {
        var cell = $(this);
        var field = e.sender.columns[cell.index()].field;
        var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(cell.closest("tr"));

        cell.toggleClass("no-dirty",
            originalDataItems[dataItem.id][field] == dataItem[field]);
      });
    });
  }
  ```
- The custom CSS class can be used to hide the dirty mark like this:

  ```
  .no-dirty .k-dirty {
      display: none;
  }
  ```
- Finally, remove all items from the `originalDataItems` collection when all pending changes are saved, i.e. in the [`saveChanges`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-saveChanges) event.

  ```
  saveChanges: function() {
      originalDataItems = {};
  }
  ```

Here is a complete example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/ivOBU

One thing to point out is that even though the dirty marks will be hidden, the respective data item will still be [`dirty`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#fields-dirty) and subject to syncing with the remote data service. This is a minor issue when [`batch`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-batch) editing is used (as in your case), but if you want to prevent unnecessary data transfer, enhance the `save` handler and reset the unmodified data items' `dirty` field to `false`.