# kendo grid cell value when changed and reverted to orginal value before save shows the dirty flag

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In a kendo grid, in a row when I change a grid cell value, it shows up a dirty flag a red mark to indicate that value is changed, when i move back to same row and revert the value back to orginal value even then it shows dirty flag red mark, 
here is the example, 
All this is done before saving:
Value = High, I changed it to value = Low(shows the red mark), now then i changed it back to value = High before saving,  so how to compare that if the value is same dont give the changed mark and update and update it only when the value is changed, 
Below is my code.

Each time the edit is triggred, i want to hold the orginal value and then compare if with new value and if old n new are different i want to add dirty cell class. so how can i hold the orginal value unless i click on save, i want to hold orginal value on evry edit change function

```
change: function (e) {
            {
                options.model.AssignedTo = e.sender.text();
                options.model.AssignedToId = e.sender.value();
                options.mod`enter code here`el.dirty = true;
                container.removeClass("k-edit-cell");
                container.addClass("k-dirty-cell");
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.
I am not a fan of global variables, but looks like you don't have a option here.

```
var firstDropDownFieldId = 0;
var _ticketId = 0;
function dropDownEditor(container, options) {
    if (firstDropDownFieldId === 0 || _ticketId === 0 || _ticketId !== options.model.Id) {
        firstDropDownId = options.model.dropdownId;
        _ticketId = options.model.Id;
    }
    editDropDown(container, options);
}
function editDropDown(container, options) {
    $(field).appendTo(container);
    var thisDropDownList = $("#DropDown").kendoDropDownList({
        autoBind: false,
        dataSource: datSource,
        change: function(e) {
            {
                options.model.DropDownField= e.sender.text();
                options.model.DropDownFieldId= e.sender.value();
                options.model.dirty = true;
                container.removeClass("k-edit-cell");
                container.addClass("k-dirty-cell");
                if (parseInt(e.sender.value()) === firstDropdownId && options.model.Id === _ticketId) {
                    options.model.dirty = false;
                    container.removeClass("k-dirty-cell");
                    container.addClass("k-edit-cell");
                }
            };
        }
    }).data("kendoDropDownList");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following thread, which discusses the same topic and includes an example of the suggested approach:

[How to compare and display kendo dirty flag upon editing only if the old value and new value are different before saving the grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514907/how-to-compare-and-display-kendo-dirty-flag-upon-editing-only-if-the-old-value-a/39549323#39549323)